# Replace Fragment showing both fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is problem with my fragment, they are showed together, one on the second fragment. How to disapear, and only show one of them?

Definiton:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    fr = new avc);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = ((TestingActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.test, fr);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            });
```

And definiton of container below:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Where is the second fragment? I see only one fragment being added. Has the other fragment a different tag?

Comment: you are using only one fragment then how can it would be replaced

Comment: First remove then add the new one ...

Comment: @quicklearner If they are in the same frame then the replace will take care of the remove for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some thing like this. Make a function for showing a fragment and call each time this function with different parameter.

eg. If You want to show "HomeFragment" then call displayView(0) and if you want to show "FindPeopleFragment" then call displayView(1)

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```